# Heroku environment variables unvisible in React app despite using dotenv

Tags: reactjs, heroku, environment-variables, dotenv

I have my heroku variables set like that:

[image]

(`MODE` is inserted because I thought that `NODE_ENV` may be getting overwritten)

In my React app I do this:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();
console.log(process.env)
```

But in my console (under the heroku URL of course) I see only:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution was changing the name of `KEY` to `REACT_APP_KEY` and restarting all dynos - we can do this here:

[image]